# Is it possible to modify my Bios?

Tags: boot, bios, operating-systems, uefi

I have a ASUS M81C tablet, which have a AMI aptio Class 3 32-bit UEFI without CSM, so I can't boot any OS designed for 64-bit UEFI or legacy BIOS, I'm trying to bypass/cascade boot one, but I also think it will be better if I can flash a modded UEFI with 64-bit or CSM, is it possible?

Comment: The firmware is specifically built for your device. So it’s not really “modify” but “make a new one” which is virtually impossible. Linux can boot from 32-bit UEFI no problem.

Comment: You're asking an XY question.

Comment: Daniel B: So there's no way to read out the current one and modify it?

Comment: If your device doesn't have a 64-bit there is a technical reason

Comment: Ramhound: Fortunately there's not: https://blogs.intel.com/evangelists/2015/07/22/why-cheap-systems-run-32-bit-uefi-on-x64-systems/

Comment: Making the sort of changes you want to make is theoretically possible, but it's not easy. You could look into [Coreboot,](https://www.coreboot.org/) which is an open source firmware implementation, which takes optional payloads to implement BIOS, UEFI, or other environments. If you're very, very lucky, there's a pre-built Coreboot for your device. Chances are there isn't, in which case you could build one -- but if you make a mistake, you could easily brick your device. This is something to try only if you're proficient at such things.